Unique constraint failed on the constraint: `_id_`

model CartItem {
cartItemId  String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
createdAt    DateTime @default(now())
updatedAt    DateTime @updatedAt
cart         Cart?     @relation(fields: [email], references: [email])
email String  
price Int
name String
description String
productId String
image Json?
order Order? @relation(fields: [orderId], references: [id])
orderId String? @db.ObjectId
}

model Order {
id String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
email String
createdAt    DateTime @default(now())
updatedAt    DateTime @updatedAt
status OrderStatus @default(IN_PROCESS)
cart CartItem[]
}

for the above models in the prisma schema file, when i try to create an order, i'm getting the following error
Invalid prisma.order.create() invocation:

Unique constraint failed on the constraint: _id_ 

I tried going through the docs but could not find any solution.
NOTE: I am able to create an order if I pass an empty array in the cart field for order.

What does your create statement look like? What are the values?
